# Xcode beta generates App cannot be opened because of a problem

Tags: macos, xcode12

Check with the developer to make sure MyApp works with this version of macOS.

After trying to use `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, when the App receives the callback, it shows the error:

[image]

The same error is showed after an attempt to generate the app and open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because your code is referring to either a non existing library or is pointing to the wrong directory where your code should look for such library. Please check the rpath you are using. Usually, you should place any dylibs inside a `Frameworks` folder inside your bundle and thus your rpath should start like this: `../Frameworks/InternalAPI.framework (...)`

Comment: You are right, I changed the framework to be embedded and it starts working. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.